# Ssrs expression returns #error when I open my report and see the total

Tags: ssrs-2008

```
=if(Fields!Type6.Value="S","",Sum(Fields!Col6.Value))
```

this is above is a expression which i used for a Sum of column which don't Contains "S"

What I have tried:

this Expression return #Error
Hide   Copy Code

```
if(Fields!Type6.Value="S","",Sum(Fields!Col6.Value))
```

This Works Fine But it will sum up also alphanumeric column numeric characters
Hide   Copy Code

```
if(Fields!Type6.Value="S","",Val(Sum(Fields!Col6.Value)))
```

i have used dynamic column so i don't know which is numeric column or string
so plz help me to out from this

Answer (score 0):

By entering "" and a sum you are causing SSRS to try and add a string and a number. Change it to

```
=if(Fields!Type6.Value="S",cint(0),Sum(Fields!Col6.Value))
```

or

```
=if(Fields!Type6.Value="S",cdec(0),Sum(Fields!Col6.Value))
```